# RewriteRule doesn't change the location in http response header

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I have this code in .htaccess file to redirect all pages in domain1.com to another domain:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work. I checked the response header with firebug but the Location directive has still domain1.com instead of domain2.com . It seems it hasn't changed. I read somewhere that some servers needs a question mark in the rule but I don't know where should I put it. My OS is debian sqeeze and the apache version is 2.2.16 .

edited: 
this problem cause a loop and the firefox gives :

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
*   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
      cookies.
```

My server is behind a pound server.

Would you help me?

Comment: What other rules are in the .htaccess file? You might want to consider just using the Apache 'Redirect' directive in the httpd.conf or virtual domain container.

Comment: I delete other rules and it still doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're redirecting all traffic to the domain, then I would recommend [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). It's far more efficient than `mod_rewrite`. Especially if this is your only `RewriteRule`.

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.domain2.com
```

Comment: I have posted the code in the question : RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Remove the `RewriteRule` and use what I have provided above. Put it above the `mod_rewrite` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Are both domains served by the same document root? If so, you need to prevent it from redirecting when domain2.com is requested:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Then is something at domain2.com is redirecting back to domain1.com?

Comment: No it is completely clean from any domain1.com expression.

Comment: it make some changes when I add ? character in the rule but it is not what I want.